# Google Maps Api inverts KML Layer after Zoom

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I do have a strange Problem with Google Maps API and a KML file.

When i initialize the Map with KML, everything works like charm. 
Now my problem: After zooming into the map (zoom Level 10) the KML Layer inverts.

Here is the example:

```js
var settings,map,marker,infowindow,consultant_fname,consultant_lname,consultant_zip,consultant_city,mapOptions;
var markers = [];


$(document).ready(function(){
            mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.643186, 13.760376),
    scrollwheel: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
     style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
     position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
    },
    scaleControl: true,
    streetViewControl: false,
    panControl:true,
    panControlOptions : {
     position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
    },
   };

   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap'),mapOptions);
    
            var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('https://www.creditnet.at/austria_3.kml',{
    preserveViewport: true,
    suppressInfoWindows: true,
    map: map,
   });
   ctaLayer.setMap(map);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<div id="gmap" style="width:700px;height:700px;"></div>
```

Hopefully anyone can help me.

Regards M.

Comment: Please file a bug here: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Maps%20API%20v3%20-%20Bug. Be sure to include all the relevant information.

Comment: similar bug report: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8011

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a bug in the KML renderer.

As a workaround, you could use a third party KML parser (like [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) or [geoxml-v3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/)), geoxml3 doesn't seem to have that artifact:

[Example using geoxml3 (and a slightly modified KML to cover the whole world)](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_winding_linktoB.html?lat=47.348768&lng=13.463745&zoom=7&type=m&filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/austria_3a.kml)

Note that for complex KML the tiled based rendering of KmlLayer will be more efficient and you may run into performance issues with the 3rd party parsers.